# discord.py Помогите как сделать ссылку на крафт. Python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import aiohttp


TOKEN = '*&$^$*&*@&($!)!(@$&*!@^$*&!^)@(_$!)@*&$'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.command()
async def craft(ctx, *, text):
    http1=str('https://minecraft-inside.ru/crafting/#')
    http2=str({text})
    http3= http1+http2
    await ctx.send(http3)
#Ссылка на крафт должна выглядеть так: https://minecraft-inside.ru/crafting/#Алмазный_блок
#А в чате ссылка вот такая: https://minecraft-inside.ru/crafting/#%7B%27Алмазный_блок%27%7D
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто использовать f-строки

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import aiohttp


TOKEN = '*&$^$*&*@&($!)!(@$&*!@^$*&!^)@(_$!)@*&$'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.command()
async def craft(ctx, *, text):
    http = str(f"https://minecraft-inside.ru/crafting/#{text}")
    await ctx.send(http)
bot.run(TOKEN)
```